# how and when to fetch return from awaitable(async) method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am pretty sure, this was answered already and I read many related stuff but somehow I am not getting it to work in my code. Here is the exact code base.

I have this async method in my library, that returns a string upon doing some DB entries:

```
public class MyLibrary
{
public async Task<string> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    return await DoAsync();
} 

// some private method, with multiple parameters
private Task<string> DoAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => Do());
}
}
```

Now on UI, below resulted a frozen state or deadlock:

```
var myTask = MyLibraryobject.DoSomethingAsync();
console.Write(myTask.Result);
```

Since my call is awaitable, I think, UI thread waits for my call to finish its business and populate the result, doesn't it? Or since the call is running on another thread, the task might not yet completed when my cursor hits the line 2. So what now? the cursor will wait till the task gets completed or the line 2 gets executed whenever the task gets completed? sounds synchronous to me..

Also if at all, I want to 'exlicitly' wait till the task gets finished, how do i enforce that? some posts, suggested in doing like below, which gave me the result, but created some more confusion:

```
var myTask = Task.Run(async () => await MyLibraryobject.DoSomethingAsync());
myTask.Wait();
console.Write(myTask.Result);
```

What is happening above? why should i create another task and set it to wait? can't I wait for the thread, used by the async method? Again, i am clearly missing some basic stuff here.

Lastly, this is an async call, but the UI thread is waiting for it to be completed thus gives me an impression that it's synchronous. Am I thinking it right? Then what is the main purpose of async methods, which return something, and UI waits for it to complete?

Also what's the difference between a fire-and-forget call being non-async and async? is there any benefit of returning Task, instead of void, for such calls?

I am pretty sure, some broken link that connects all these pieces together in my brain. Can someone explain that to me, please??

Comment: When you call an async method you have no guarantee that the content will be run in a different thread than the calling one. That's why sometime you should wrap it in `Task.Run` (Or `Task.Factory.StartNew`). In addintion, when you call `myTask.Result`, `myTask.Wait()` is implicit. To avoid blocking thread UI, you should mark your event handler method as async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now on UI, below resulted a frozen state or deadlock:

```
var myTask = MyLibraryobject.DoSomethingAsync();
```

This is blocking the UI because it is not awaited. You simply need to await an async method

```
string res = await MyLibraryobject.DoSomethingAsync();
```

and the above should be placed in the UI inside an async context too.

Edit - reply to comment do "you mean another wrapper async method, which returns `Task<string>`..."? No,I don't. When I wrote "inside an async context" I meant to add the async keyword to a subscribed event, like a button click, if you are in the code behind or to your delegate command implementation, if you are in a more advanced MVVM implementation of the GUI.

Furthermore, your class library is supposed to do something truly asynchronous, not just starting a task and wrapping it inside a formally async method, like it is your `DoAsync`.

Edit - in reply to comment "how should avoid" it? If you can't do async all the way, just keep the library and the API sync and unblock the UI by starting a separate thread to call the sync api.

Comment: you mean another wrapper async method, which returns Task<string>, which has a call like, `return await MyLibraryobject.DoSomethingAsync()` ? Also, i don't understand what else should i do in my library method?

Comment: Ok. I am calling this library method in an API method and that's the reason I haven't used the 'await' keyword directly here, as it would force me to add 'async' keyword to the API method. So I created a wrapper, which simply returns the task, which is being awaited, like `return await MyLibraryobject.DoSomethingAsync()`. But that did not work. Upon your comment, I added 'async' to the API method and used await and got the result, just you mentioned. My confusion is, why it didn't work earlier, when I made the same 'await' in the wrapper. Does creating a wrapper references another task?

Comment: Also, I understood that I should not expose an asynchronous counterpart that simply wraps the synchronous method in Task.Run. That's what exactly I've done with my library method; it was sync before and I made it async, by wrapping inside Task.Run. How should I avoid such practices and still have an async version?

Comment: @Skip if you can't create an async version of the API method, stay always sync and avoid exposing or using an async version of the library either. In that case you'll simply use a different thread from the UI, eventually.

Comment: understood! I have few other questions, with my own scenarios, and i shall post them as separate questions, may be!! As of now, i understood that in order to access an async returned value, i have to use 'await' inline.
I still don’t understand the reason behind, why the wrapper thing failed, as explained in the comment under @Stephen Cleary’s post though!!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably start with my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and follow up with my article on [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). They answer almost all your questions.

For the details...

> how and when to fetch return from awaitable(async) method

You should use `await` to get the result from an async task.

> I have this async method in my library, that returns a string upon doing some DB entries

Then it should not be using `Task.Run`. It should be using naturally-asynchronous APIs, e.g., Entity Framework's `FirstAsync`.

> Since my call is awaitable, I think, UI thread waits for my call to finish its business and populate the result, doesn't it?

No. The UI is blocking because your code is calling `Result`. `Result` is a blocking call.

> sounds synchronous to me..

That's because you're making it synchronous by using `Result`. If you use `await`, the code will execute *serially*, but *asynchronously*.

> Also if at all, I want to 'exlicitly' wait till the task gets finished, how do i enforce that?

Your code is already doing that. It's explicitly blocking until the task is complete. If you change it to properly use `await`, it will be explicitly waiting (but not blocking) until the task is complete.

> some posts, suggested in doing like below

No. Don't use `Task.Run` unnecessarily.

> can't I wait for the thread, used by the async method?

Pure async methods don't have threads that they use.

> Then what is the main purpose of async methods, which return something, and UI waits for it to complete?

Async makes sense when it's consumed with `await`.

Comment: Thanks; I read your stuff. Since things didn't work out, thats when I became doubtful of my own understanding. I added my explanation of why I didn't add 'await' inline in the other comment. do you mind explaining the stuff behind it?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. If you're using `async` and `await` all the way, then it'll work with or without the wrapper.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't be clear on my problem!
Test1:
`MyOriginalMethod() { string result = Lib.AsyncMethod().Result; // does not work }`

Test2:
`MyOriginalMethod() { string result = wrapper.wrapperAsyncMethod().Result; // does not work }
wrapperAsyncMethod() {return await Lib.AsyncMethod();}`

Test3:
`Async MyOriginalMethod() { string result = await Lib.AsyncMethod(); // works }`

And MyOriginalMethod() is an API method, and the Test3, what I mean by 'inline await'